# How can I train for high specificity for a single class in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, time-series, recurrent-neural-network

I have a GRU network that receives a sequence of data, and labels it as class 0 or class 1. I want the model to have a high specificity for class 0 (being at least >= 0.8), while making sure that it still has good sensitivity (hopefully up to nearly 0.5).

How can I do this in Tensorflow? Is there a way to let the loss be determined by the combination of specificity and sensitivity *for a single class?* I don't really care about the accuracy of predictions for class 1, but, in this case, it's really important that the predictions are right when class 0 is predicted, while still having a fair number of predictions for class 0 (at least predicting class 0 half of the time that the labels would be for class 0 as well).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the relevant code I have so far:

```
states_concat = tf.concat(axis=1, values=states)
logits = tf.layers.dense(states_concat, n_outputs)
softmax = tf.nn.softmax(logits=logits)
xentropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=logits)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(xentropy)

#Set up the optimizer with gradient clipping to minimize the chance of exploding values
optimizer = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate, momentum=0.9, use_nesterov=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my own question.

For anyone else who runs into this trouble, other terms that are useful are precision and recall, where precision measures: truePositives/(truePositives + falsePositives), and recall measures the sensitivity.

The links that helped me are:
https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-penalize-false-positive-in-deep-learning-tensorflow
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits